# Picking a single line from a text file by its line number

Tags: unix, bash, shell, unix-shell

In a Unix shell, how can I pick a single line from a text file by its line number?

Say I want whatever is at line 3 in animals.txt to be written to stdout (bat bat bat).

```
monkey monkey monkey
cat cat cat
bat bat bat
horse horse horse
```

Is there a standard program or simple way to do this?

(There's also the case where the text file does not contain enough lines to contain the line number you ask for)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way:

```
sed -n '3p' file
```

Here's another:

```
head -n 3 file | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Using head/tail like that didn't occur to me, for which I'm a bit ashamed :-)